# How can I define in Visual Studio a new constant?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I need to define a new constant in Visual Studio.

I explain: I have a custom Compile Configuration (sorry I'm not sure the name is exact, I have a localized version of VS), and I need to define another constant besides the TRACE and DEBUG ones.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

- in the top of one of your code files, write the line:

  #define MYCONSTANT

then elsewhere within the same file you can refer to it with code like

```
#ifdef MYCONSTANT
    ... some code...
#endif
```

- right click on a project file, select Properties. In the Build tab, you have a checkbox for each of the two constants you mentioned - above that is a textbox, enter your new constant there. You don't assign it a value, just the fact that it is declared is all you need.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, I found it.
I was expecting "Custom defined constants" or something like that instead of the label of THAT textbox